# How do I initialize this struct?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Sorry for being not specific, but...

Suppose I have this struct:

```
struct OptionData
{
    Desc desc;
    bool boolValue;
    std::string stringValue;
    int intValue;
    double numberValue;
};
```

which I'm using this way:

```
OptionData isWritePatchesOptionData = {isWritePatchesDesc, {}, {}, {}, {}};
```

As I have lots of those options, I'd like to do s.t. like this:

```
<type_here> OptionDataList = {{}, {}, {}, {}};
```

so I can do:

```
OptionData isSeamCutOptionData = {isSeamCutDesc, OptionDataList};
```

but really on the spot I can't figure what type_here would be...
Or maybe is not possible in this form... I mean, without creating an OptionDataList object into the OptionData struct... but that clearly would be redundant...

Comment: why not use a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide default initializers.  Using

```
struct OptionData
{
    Desc desc{};
    bool boolValue{};
    std::string stringValue{};
    int intValue{};
    double numberValue{};
};
```

Everything in the struct will be value initialized meaning objects with a constructor will be default constructed and objects without a constructor will be zero initialized.

This lets you write

```
OptionData isWritePatchesOptionData = {isWritePatchesDesc}; // same as using {isWritePatchesDesc, {}, {}, {}, {}};
// and
OptionData isSeamCutOptionData = {isSeamCutDesc};
```

and now all of the other members are in a default/zero state.

Comment: I think this is the straighest. Also I could do: OptionData isWritePatchesOptionData = {isWritePatchesDesc, {}}; - but that probably result in indeterminated initialization for the struct members... but not sure.

Comment: @Kabu That would work as well.  Everything will still be value initialized so default for constructor and zero for non-constructors.